# What exactly do the terms of $(f \circ g)'''$ mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, tensors

Say, $g: X\to Y$ and $f: Y\to Z$ are smooth.

One can find $(f \circ g)'''$ by using the [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):

$$(f \circ g)''' =(f'''\circ g)(g')^3 + 3(f''\circ g)g'g'' + (f'\circ g)g'''$$

But my current level doesn't allow me to understand  $(g')^3$ (I guess it has something to do with tensors yet they are well beyond my text).

So I wanted to express it in more familiar terms by recalling that

$$(f \circ g)''':X\to \mathcal L^3(X;Z)$$

would it be something like

\begin{align*} 
(f\circ g)'''(x)[a,b,c] & = f'''(g(x))\Big[g'(x)[a], g'(x)[b],g'(x)[c]\Big]
\\ &  + 3f''(g(x))\Big[g'(x)[a],g''(x)[b,c]\Big]
\\ &  + f'(g(x))\Big[g'''(x)[a,b,c]\Big]
\end{align*}

Does it make sense? How can we derive the extended version per hand?

Comment: $(g')^3$ simply means $g'(x)g'(x)g'(x)$?

Comment: @mathse: well, in some sense yes, but it's meaningless without context. I mean, when one sees functions written like this, one thinks either about product or about composition. And it seems to be neither nor.

Comment: Does the same trouble arise for you when you see: $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ and $(f\circ g)''(x)$?

Comment: @mathse: I guess, one could see $f'(g(x))g'(x)$ as $f'(g(x))\Big[g'(x)[1]\Big]$

Comment: If there is some deeper truth in this, @Leo Schmidt, please go ahead and post an answer. I don't usually attribute a whole lot of meaning to derivatives, so my answer may have been ignorant.